# Issue with Nokogiri::Slop getting node attributes?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an SVG file containing:

```
<text x="10"  y="20"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">SVG text styling</text>
<text x="85"  y="150"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">This is the second piece of text</text>
<text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">This is the third piece of text</text>

         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">test text</text>
         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">data data</text>
         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">txt txt txt</text>
```

I want to get some data from it. I am using this code using  `Nokogiri::Slop`:

```
@test = Nokogiri::Slop(File.open("./file.svg"))
```

and this ERb:

```
<% @test.xpath('//text').map do |i|%>
<%=i%>
<%  end  %>
```

This works, but my problem now is how to get the children  `font-family,font-size,fill,stroke`

I’ve tried this code

```
<%=i.("[@stroke]").text.content %>
```

but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What happens when you run it? Do you get an exception? What does that exception say? Does it run but not generate the output you want? If so, show that output and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the data in an ERB, you should first convert it into something more friendly in your controller. This code will result in an array of hashes you can peel apart in the view:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<svg>
<text x="10"  y="20"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">SVG text styling</text>
<text x="85"  y="150"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">This is the second piece of text</text>
<text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">This is the third piece of text</text>

         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">test text</text>
         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">data data</text>
         <text x="45"  y="250"
  style="font-family: Helvetica;
         font-size  : 24;
         fill       : #ff0000;
         stroke     : #000000;">txt txt txt</text>
</svg>
EOT
```

At this point Nokogiri has an XML document.

Here's all it takes to walk the `<text>` nodes:

```
text_styles = doc.search('text').map { |text|
  Hash[text['style'].split(';').map{ |attr| attr.split(':').map(&:strip) }]
}
```

Which when run, will return `text_styles` containing:

```
text_styles 
# => [{"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"},
#     {"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"},
#     {"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"},
#     {"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"},
#     {"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"},
#     {"font-family"=>"Helvetica",
#      "font-size"=>"24",
#      "fill"=>"#ff0000",
#      "stroke"=>"#000000"}]
```

The code reads the data and parses it as XML. Then, using `search` it looks for a CSS selector `text`. Why CSS? It's easier to read.

Once a `<text>` node is found it retrieves the `style` attribute from the node, then splits its value on `;`, then, for each of the resulting arrays, it splits them on `:` and strips the leading/trailing whitespace.

Finally it converts the resulting array of arrays into a hash and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

The `font-family`, `font-size`, `fill` and `stroke` items in your XML are *not* XML attributes, so you cannot get them (directly) with Nokogiri. They are part of a string that is the value of the `style` attribute. You will have to obtain that string, and then parse it somehow in Ruby.

Here’s an example showing how to get the values of these four things for the first `text` element:

```
# first get the complete string:
styles = @test.at_xpath("//text/@style").value

# next split the string into key values pairs on ;, then each pair
# into spearate strings on :, and create a hash with the result
style_hash = Hash[style1.split(/\s*;\s*/).map { |s| s.split(/\s*:\s*/)}]
```

Comment: I know the concept now and it worked well with me 
but how i can get the Xpath lenght

Comment: @AndroidMan I don’t understand what you mean. Do you mean how to get all the `text/@style` nodes? Note that I’ve used `at_path` to simplify the example, which only returns the first node – use `xpath` to get tham all. Have a look at [the Tin Man’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310518/214790), he includes a similar example that extracts all the nodes.